# Request user input in pre or post build event - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, user-input, post-build-event, pre-build-event, build-events

I want the user to approve an action in the pre or post build event by requesting an user input - like 'y' or 'n'. Thereby the user can cancel the task if he forgot to switch the Configuration by mistake for example.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
   //ask user to type in some text
)
```

Can someone provide me an example? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything. If possible I would like to avoid calling another batch file.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initiate your command in the build event command window with "start /wait".

Example:

```
start /wait powershell.exe -file $(ProjectDir)\UpdateAssemblyVersion.ps1 -configuration $(ConfigurationName)
```

Then you can request user input by using Read-Host.